# High Validation F1 score but low testing F1 score

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, overfitting, boosting, smote

I am working on a dataset related to an insurance company and the objective is to predict if the insurance buyer will claim their travel insurance or not.

Training data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dphi-official/Datasets/master/travel_insurance/Training_set_label.csv

Testing data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dphi-official/Datasets/master/travel_insurance/Testing_set_label.csv

I have written the below code so far: When I submit the predictions on the website (it's similar to Kaggle), I get F1 score of 2.8850777368167977 while the 5 fold cross validation F1 score is around 74%. I read that in severely imbalanced datasets, there is not much smote can do if the variation within the minority classes is a lot. ([Source](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11656/overfitting-for-minority-class-after-smote-w-random-forests)) However, there are some entries on the website with F1 score of 12-15. Any suggestions on how can I improve the F1 score?

```
  #We will fill the missing values in Gender column with the mode value for the "Gender" column
  train_df['Gender'].fillna(train_df['Gender'].mode()[0],inplace=True)
  test_df['Gender'].fillna(test_df['Gender'].mode()[0],inplace=True)
    
  #"Duration" column has negative values. Replace it with median of "Duration" column as time cannot be -ve
  mask=train_df[train_df['Duration']<0]
  mask['Duration']=train_df['Duration'].median()
  train_df=pd.concat([train_df[~train_df['Duration']<0],mask])
    
  #Same idea for "Net Sales" and "Age" column. Repeat this for test_df
  ...
    
    
 y=train_df['Claim']
 train_df.drop(['Claim'],inplace=True,axis=1)
 X=train_df
    
 # applying the transformations in cross validation

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

cv = StratifiedKFold(5) 
valid_f1=[]
train_f1=[]
f1_global=0

X=np.array(X)
y=np.array(y)

for train_index,valid_index in cv.split(X,y):
  X_train,y_train= X[train_index],y[train_index]
  X_valid,y_valid= X[valid_index],y[valid_index]

  #apply encoders
  encoder=ce.JamesSteinEncoder()

  encoded_train=encoder.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
  encoded_valid=encoder.transform(X_valid)


  #apply PCA to get the required number of features
  pca = PCA(0.99)

  reduced_encoded_train=pca.fit_transform(encoded_train)
  reduced_encoded_valid=pca.transform(encoded_valid)

  n_features = pca.n_components_
  print("Number of features selected:",n_features)

  #applying quantile transformation
  qt = QuantileTransformer(random_state=0)

  train_num_transformed=qt.fit_transform(reduced_encoded_train)
  valid_num_transformed=qt.transform(reduced_encoded_valid)

  #applying robust scaler
  rs=RobustScaler()

  train_num_scaled=rs.fit_transform(train_num_transformed)
  valid_num_scaled=rs.transform(valid_num_transformed)

  #apply SMOTE
  bsmen=BorderlineSMOTE('minority',random_state=12)

  X_train_smen,y_train_smen = bsmen.fit_sample(train_num_scaled,y_train)
  
  #model using SVC
  svc=SVC()
  svc.fit(X_train_smen,y_train_smen)

  #fine tuning Support Vector

  #The strength of the regularization is inversely proportional to C.
  #reducing C to increase regularization and avoid overfitting
  
  tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4],
                       'C': [0.001, 0.010, 0.0001]
                       }, 
                      {'kernel': ['sigmoid'], 'gamma': [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4],
                       'C': [0.001, 0.010, 0.0001]
                       },
                      {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [0.001, 0.010, 0.0001]
                       }
                      ]

  tuned_SVC=BayesSearchCV(svc,tuned_parameters,cv=5,scoring='f1',random_state=12,n_jobs=-1)
  tuned_SVC.fit(X_train_smen,y_train_smen)                      

  #validation dataset predicting 
  valid_predictions = tuned_SVC.predict(valid_num_scaled)

  #training dataset predicting 
  train_predictions = tuned_SVC.predict(X_train_smen)  

  #calculating f1_score on validation predictions
  valid_f1_scor = f1_score(y_valid,valid_predictions)
  print("******")
  print("Support Vector:")
  print("Validation F1 score:",valid_f1_scor)

  #calculating f1_score on training predictions
  train_f1_scor = f1_score(y_train_smen,train_predictions)

  print("Training F1 score:",train_f1_scor)

  #saving results of SVC as it is performing the best
  if valid_f1_scor>f1_global:
    # save the model to disk
    filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
    pickle.dump(svc, open(filename, 'wb'))

    #save fitted encoders, transformers and scalers 
    filename = 'finalized_dim_reducer.sav'
    pickle.dump(pca, open(filename, 'wb'))

    filename = 'finalized_encoder.sav'
    pickle.dump(encoder, open(filename, 'wb'))

    filename = 'finalized_transformer.sav'
    pickle.dump(qt, open(filename, 'wb'))

    filename = 'finalized_scaler.sav'
    pickle.dump(rs, open(filename, 'wb'))

    f1_global=valid_f1_scor
```

Comment: This is a classic sign of [overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/294661/28500). Perhaps your boosted model is learning too quickly? Also, F1 depends on a (potentially implicit) choice of probability cutoff for making the class distinctions, and like accuracy is [not a good primary measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/28500) of model performance. The SMOTE used in training might also be posing a problem when you apply the model to the test set.

Comment: Yes, it is overfitting. I replaced XGBoost with regularized SVM as XGBoost was overfitting more than SVM. I have also placed SMOTE within cross validation so that SMOTE isn't applied on the entire dataset but only on the training part. The F1 score improved slightly but it's still in the range of 2-3%.

Comment: @AasthaJha. Same issue here. I have a high validation F1 score but a low test F1 score.